# Datepicker after replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, replacewith

I can make a jQuery datepicker work if the textfield is created when the website is loaded but if I make it appear with a .`replaceWith()` function, it wont work.

Here is my code when it just appears when the website is loaded:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZnKMX/3/

And here is the code where I create a textfield using replaceWith:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZnKMX/4/

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();` after the element is created

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnKMX/5/)